# What's a better way to decrease cardinality when serializing records

Tags: powershell

I need to transfer data from one vendor's system to another.

The source vendor has a view that generates data that combines invoice and line-item data into records w/ line-item cardinality:

```
"Invoice","Date","Line","Description","Price"
"A","2/1/2020","1","something","100"
"A","2/1/2020","2","something else","75"
"B","1/1/2020","1","lorem ipsum","25"
"C","12/15/2020","1","foo bar","10.25"
"C","12/15/2020","2","foo bar","99.99"
```

The data needs to be transmitted, however, as a unit that combines the invoice and its line items:

```
<I>
  <Invoice>A</Invoice>
  <Date>02/01/20</Date>
  <Items>
    <Item>
      <Line>1</Line>
      <Description>something</Description>
      <Price>100</Price>
    </Item>
    <Item>
     <Line>2</Line>
     <Description>something else</Description>
     <Price>75</Price>
    </Item>
  </Items>
</I>
```

Towards this end, I've written the following:

```
# create testing data
function Get-Data
{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Invoice = 'A'
        Date='2/1/2020'
        Line=1
        Description = 'something'
        Price = 100.0
    }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Invoice = 'A'
        Date='2/1/2020'
        Line=2
        Description = 'something else'
        Price = 75.0
    }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Invoice = 'B'
        Date='1/1/2020'
        Line=1
        Description = 'lorem ipsum'
        Price = 25.0
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Invoice = 'C'
        Date='12/15/2020'
        Line=1
        Description = 'foo bar'
        Price = 10.25
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Invoice = 'C'
        Date='12/15/2020'
        Line=2
        Description = 'foo bar'
        Price = 99.99
    }

}

# serialize related line items
function ConvertTo-LineItemXml {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [int]$Line,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$Description,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [decimal]$Price
    )
    begin {}
    process
    {
        $xml += "<Item><Line>$Line</Line><Description>$Description</Description><Price>$Price</Price></Item>"
    }
    end
    {
        $xml
    }
}

# convert data to required Xml message and post
function Send-Invoice {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$Invoice,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [datetime]$Date,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [pscustomobject]$Items
    )

    begin {}
    process {

        $xml = "<I><Invoice>$Invoice</Invoice><Date>$($Date.ToString('MM/dd/yy'))</Date><Items>"

        $xml += $Items | ForEach-Object { 
            $_ | ConvertTo-LineItemXml 
        } 

        $xml += '</Items></I>'

        Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $Uri -Body $xml -ContentType 'application/xml'
    }
    end {}
}

# controller 
Get-Data | 
    # group by invoice
    Group-Object {$_.Invoice} |
        # for each group
        ForEach-Object {

            # get invoice-specific information from the group's first record
            $i = $_.Group | Select-Object -First 1 Invoice, Date

            # get the line-item-specific information from the group's records
            $li = $_.Group | Select-Object Line, Description, Price

            # assign to property
            $i | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Items' -Value $li

            # return structure
            $i 

        } | 
Send-Invoice # format as xml and post
```

I should probably move `ConvertTo-LineItemXml` from within `Send-Invoice` to allow the caller to have more control over the processing.

What other improvements can I make?

Comment: Does `Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $Uri -Body $xml -ContentType 'application/xml'` work as expected? I'm asking because body of a _fixed_ `$Uri` would be rewritten with the last `$xml` i.e. invoice C for given input data, and other invoices are lost?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `XElement`.
It is especially useful when constructing XML.

```
using namespace System.Xml.Linq
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml.Linq

Get-Data | Group-Object Invoice | ForEach-Object {

    $items = $_.Group | ForEach-Object {
        [XElement]::new('Item', @(
            [XElement]::new('Line', $_.Line)
            [XElement]::new('Description', $_.Description)
            [XElement]::new('Price', $_.Price)))
    }

    $xml = [XElement]::new('I', @(
        [XElement]::new("Invoice", $_.Name)
        [XElement]::new("Date", $_.Group[0].Date)
        [XElement]::new('Items', $items)
    )).ToString()

    $xml
}
```